# Obtain the client id from Ustream

Tags: android, api, oauth, clientid

I am developing a android streaming app, I will like to use the Ustream api to streaming a video from the app, i know how to do it, my problem is that I need a client id and a client secret id to validate the user's credentials using OAuth 2.0, but I have no idea where to get it since that in the api documentation is not explained and I can not find it anywhere else

Any help is highly appreciated

Regards

Comment: Did you find client id ?

Comment: yes, but you have to paid for it, so we end it up using youtube only